# How to disable vibration for Timer alerts?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, clock, vibrate

In `iOS Settings / Notifications`, I can control whether alerts use vibration or sound or vibration-and-sound for Calendar, FaceTime, Mail, Messages, Phone, and Reminders apps.

In `Clock App / Alarm / Edit or Add Alarm / Sound`, I control whether alarm-clock alerts use vibration or sound or vibration-and-sound.

But I can't seem to have timer alerts (from `Clock App / Timer`) that are sound-only (no vibrate), without killing vibration for all apps.

Or am I mistaken?

Comment: It currently (Mar 2017) works that: within the clock app, if you turn off Vibration for "alarm" section, in fact it turns off vibration for "timer" section. Typical Apple screw-up.

Answer (score 1):

You are not mistaken; a very odd oversight on the part of Apple. Note that you can turn off "Vibrate on Silent" in sound settings and flip the side switch put your phone on Silent, which will disable that vibration and still make the sound (I believe).

Also note that you can turn off vibration for alarms, but for some reason not for timers. My suggestion would be to download a different timer app from the app store if you want greater customizability.

Comment: Wrong - fortunately, when you turn off the idiotic vibration FOR ALARMS, indeed that also turns it off for TIMERS.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 and iOS 14, the only way to achieve this seems to be to go to Settings > Sounds & Haptics, and turn off the "Vibrate on Ring" and/or "Vibrate on Silent".
(This is sub-optimal since this effects the whole system and not only the Timer.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the other answers, Settings > Sounds & Haptics > Vibrate on Ring. Set this to off. However, if you keep the side flip switch set to Silent, the phone will still vibrate when the timer goes off. So if you want the timer to only make the sound and not vibrate when it goes off, simply ensure that the side switch is not on silent mode and turn off “vibrate on ring”.